# How to show postgresql data in html table dynamically in NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, postgresql, html-table

Im creating a webapp and want to display every data in my postgresql database to HTML table. Does anyone know or can guide me how to retrieve postgres data and show it on my HTML table dynamically?

So i try connect to my postgresql and I able to print the data in my terminal but how can i display the output on my HTML table?

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public")); //indicates the directory for static items e.g css
const {Client} = require('pg')



app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/html/mainpage.html");
});

const client = new Client({
    user:"postgres",
    password:"12345",
    host:"localhost",
    port: 5432,
    database:"emailDemo"
})

client.connect()
.then(() => console.log("connected successfully"))
.then(() => client.query("select * from emaildata "))
.then(results => console.table(results.rows))
.catch(e => console.log("error"))
.finally(() => client.end)

app.listen(3000, function(){ 
    console.log('server is running on port 3k');
})
```

HTML

```
   <table id="zero_config" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Ingested Email</th>
         <th>Ingested Password</th>
         <th>Alert Email</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Total Rules</th>
         <th>Last update</th>
         <th>Action</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>example</td>
         <td>example</td>
         <td>example</td>
         <td>example</td>
         <td>example</td>
         <td>example</td>
         <td>
           <button type="button">Edit</button>
         </td>
       </tr>
       </tr>
     </tbody>undefined
   </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use template engines with Express to serve dynamic HTML

Have you heard of EJS? https://ejs.co/

Probably you can follow this tutorial on how to use EJS with express
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VM-2xSaDxJc